# How to correctly pass float arguments on the stack using ABI calling procedure

Tags: c++, assembly, abi

I’m not proficient in assembly language. I am trying to make a call to a function, `foo`, which takes ten floating point arguments. After the first eight, using the xmm0-xmm7 registers, I push the arguments onto the stack. I get almost correct results, except for the last two floating point values, which are the ones I put on the stack.

I presume my error is with how I am calling `push`, and alignment with the values. I’m not sure though, and I haven’t been able to figure out a solution. I think it would be a rather simple fix though.

Here is an example piece of code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>

void* foo(float a_, float b_, float c_, float d_, float e_, float f_, float g_, float h_, float i_, float j_)
{
    std::cout << "A=" << a_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B=" << b_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C=" << c_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "D=" << d_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "E=" << e_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "F=" << f_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "G=" << g_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "H=" << h_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I=" << i_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "J=" << j_ << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

struct asm_call_data
{
    void* (*_function)(...);
    float _data[10];
};

int main()
{
    asm_call_data call_data;

    call_data._function = (void* (*)(...))&foo;
    call_data._data[0] = 1.3;
    call_data._data[1] = 2.4;
    call_data._data[2] = 3.5;
    call_data._data[3] = 4.7;
    call_data._data[4] = 5.8;
    call_data._data[5] = 6.9;
    call_data._data[6] = 7.0;
    call_data._data[7] = 8.1;
    call_data._data[8] = 9.2;
    call_data._data[9] = 10.3;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        // create new stack frame
        "pushq %%rbp;\r\n\t"
        "movq %%rsp, %%rbp;\r\n\t"
        // move call data _data values into xmm0, xmm1, xmm2
        "movss 8(%%rax), %%xmm0;\r\n\t"
        "movss 12(%%rax), %%xmm1;\r\n\t"
        "movss 16(%%rax), %%xmm2;\r\n\t"
        "movss 20(%%rax), %%xmm3;\r\n\t"
        "movss 24(%%rax), %%xmm4;\r\n\t"
        "movss 28(%%rax), %%xmm5;\r\n\t"
        "movss 32(%%rax), %%xmm6;\r\n\t"
        "movss 36(%%rax), %%xmm7;\r\n\t"
        "push 40(%%rax);\r\n\t"
        "push 44(%%rax);\r\n\t"
        // align stack
        "andq $-16, %%rsp;\r\n\t"
        // make asm call
        "call 0(%%rax);\r\n\t"
        // restore stack frame
        "movq %%rbp, %%rsp;\r\n\t"
        "popq %%rbp;\r\n\t"
    :
    : "a"(&call_data)
    : "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4", "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7"
    );
}
```

Here is the outputs I get when compiling and running. I don’t know what the warning really is telling me, and in ‘I=’ I have a very off number, but the following number is correct.

```
user@HP-PC:~/Documents/Subproject$ g++ Main.cpp -o Main
Main.cpp: Assembler messages:
Main.cpp:78: Warning: indirect call without `*'
user@HP-PC:~/Documents/Subproject$ ./Main
A=1.3
B=2.4
C=3.5
D=4.7
E=5.8
F=6.9
G=7
H=8.1
I=4.51567e+27
J=10.3
user@HP-PC:~/Documents/Subproject$
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Does the rest of the assembly look correct? And, what does the warning tell me? I don’t have a line 78 in my code..

Comment: What instruction set is this?  I assume x86?

Comment: Hey, it's actually running on x64.

Comment: Should point out a major failing in this code. It can clobber the red zone.

Comment: Would backing up the red zone in a locally defined variable in my struct be a viable solution? Or is there a caveat to that?

Comment: You can adjust the stack pointer down by 128 bytes then do the work you need and then restore the stack pointer after. Which brings up the next problem, and a big one - when calling a function from inline assembly you have to save all the possible registers that may be clobbered. It isn't just the XMM registers that may be clobbered but every potential volatile register (per the calling convention)

Comment: As for the warning `call 0(%%rax)` . GNU assemblers ATT syntax has a preference that you denote the indirect call with an explicit  `*`. I believe you just have to change it to `call *0(%%rax)`

Comment: And I didn't notice at first but you do `andq $-16, %%rsp` after you push the arguments and before the call. This can potentially put another value on the stack as the first parameter. You should do the stack alignment adjustment before you push the parameters. If you align it to a 16-byte boundary and you push 2 8 byte values (16 bytes) then the stack will still be 16-byte aligned at the call.

Comment: And another thing. Among the potential missing clobbers I mentioned (because of the _CALL_) you will need to add the `memory` clobber to the clobber list.

Comment: when you ask an assembly question, you need to specify the instruction set (even if it is somewhat obvious)...put the tags in there to help yourself out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing stack alignment like that, you need to do it *before* pushing your arguments.

And, since C++ pushes arguments right-to-left, you need to push `J` (`data[9]`) before `I` (`data[8]`).

Comment: Is there a better way for doing stack alignment?